# Web Scraping: R rvest html_nodes return character(0)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Below is the code. The strange thing is that I could run it without problems yesterday, but today always returns character(0). After checking through it, I found it's because of the `html_nodes` line.

I try to replace ".photo-cards li article" with other nodes, it's still not working.

Did somebody meet the same problem and fix it? Thank you in advance for your help!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
links <- sprintf("https://www.zillow.com/sacramento-ca/%d_p", 1:11)
results <- map(links, ~ {
  # http://selectorgadget.com/
  # <body
  # class="photo-cards
  houses <- read_html(.x) %>%
    html_nodes(".photo-cards li article")
  z_id <- houses %>%
    html_attr("id")
  
  address <- houses %>%
    html_node(".list-card-addr") %>%
    html_text()
  
  price <- houses %>%
    html_node(".list-card-price") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    readr::parse_number()
  
  params <- houses %>%
    html_node(".list-card-info") %>%
    html_text()
  # number of bedrooms
  beds <- params %>%
    str_extract("\\d+(?=\\s*bds)") %>%
    as.numeric()
  # number of bathrooms
  baths <- params %>%
    str_extract("\\d+(?=\\s*ba)") %>%
    as.numeric()
  # total square footage
  house_a <- params %>%
    str_extract("[0-9,]+(?=\\s*sqft)") %>%
    str_replace(",", "") %>%
    as.numeric()
  
  tibble(price = price, beds= beds, baths=baths, house_area = house_a)
  
}
) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = 'page_no')
```

Comment: I can't open the link https://www.zillow.com/sacramento-ca/%d_p1, it reports the 400 ERROR.

Comment: @PeaceWang Did you substitute in a number for the placeholder?

Comment: What makes you think html_nodes is at fault? Seems fine to me. I did notice a warning at this point `readr::parse_number()` where it got currency rather than expected number.

Comment: Because it only returns character(0) in my PC,  and don't know why.....

Comment: What was the response status code? Did you examine the response text?